create new dataframe after performing calculations from groupby
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
ID  TradeDate    party    Deal   Asset  Start       Expire      Fixed   Quantity  MTM      Float
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Buy    HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Buy    HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   WTI    01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   WTI    01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Buy    WTI    01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00

I group the data by Start, Asset, and Deal and I perform caluculations to transform the dataframe into this:
groups = df.groupby(['Start', 'Asset', 'Deal'])

ID  TradeDate    party    Deal   Asset  Start       Expire      Fixed   Quantity  MTM      Float
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
total                                                                   3000     7500.00   

ID  TradeDate    party    Deal   Asset  Start       Expire      Fixed   Quantity  MTM      Float
1   04/11/2024   party1   Buy    HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Buy    HO     01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
total                                                                   3000     5000.00   

ID  TradeDate    party    Deal   Asset  Start       Expire      Fixed   Quantity  MTM      Float
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   WTI    01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
1   04/11/2024   party1   Sell   WTI    01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
total                                                                   3000     5000.00   

ID  TradeDate    party    Deal   Asset  Start       Expire      Fixed   Quantity  MTM      Float
1   04/11/2024   party1   Buy    WTI    01/01/2024  02/01/2024  10.00   1000     2500.00   10.00
total                                                                   1000     2500.00   

My objective is to transform these groups another time so that I can output only the data I need. The expected output for this step should look something like this:
party   Deal  Asset Start        MTM       Float
party1  Sell  HO    01/01/2024   7500.00   10.00 
party1  Buy   HO    01/01/2024   5000.00   10.00
party1  Sell  WTI   01/01/2024   5000.00   10.00
party1  Buy   WTi   01/01/2024   2500.00   10.00                                                         

Do I need to perform another groupby of some sort? or is there another function that could achieve this? Any suggestions would help.
Note: in the second step, those are individual dataframes that come from a list. You may need an intermediate step to concat these together and then get to the final output.

I think you just need pd.Groupby + .agg:
out = df.groupby(["Start", "Asset", "Deal"], sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
    {"party": "first", "MTM": "sum", "Float": "first"}
)
print(out)

Prints:
        Start Asset  Deal   party     MTM  Float
0  01/01/2024    HO  Sell  party1  7500.0   10.0
1  01/01/2024    HO   Buy  party1  5000.0   10.0
2  01/01/2024   WTI  Sell  party1  5000.0   10.0
3  01/01/2024   WTI   Buy  party1  2500.0   10.0


in the agg func, are those keywords that perform some type of action?

@iBeMeltin Yes, {"party": "first", "MTM": "sum", "Float": "first"} means: from the party column select first value, sum the MTM column and from the Float column select first value.
